# Are whoever, whichever and whatever relative pronouns?

Tags: relative-pronouns

Are **whoever** ,**whichever** and **whatever** relative pronouns which is used to modify nouns in adjective clauses?

eg:

> 1. Most workers, **whoever** was not employed by the auto manufacturer, toiled at one of the  millions of little minnow companies.
> 2. The three approaches, **whichever** works is fine, produce a more ambiguous picture of a man.
> 3. Any excessive profits, **whatever** exceeded accepted limits, would attract the notice of representatives.

Are these sentences correct? And can we use who**ever**, which**ever** and what**ever** as relative pronoun?

Answer (score 1):

These are indefinite relative pronouns, meaning they don't refer to a known noun. I've heard it say that they are the expanded form of the relative pronoun.

Since you are calling out *workers* in the first sentence, I believe you don't need the "ever".

> Most workers, who were not employed by the auto manufacturer, toiled ...

And if you left off *workers*

> Whoever was not employed by the auto manufacturer, toiled ...

Comment: I agree with you.but I was confused [this post](http://www.englishlanguageguide.com/grammar/relative-pronoun.asp)